# How to add .watch to gulpfile.js

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am using gulp for minify JS and CSS.
Everything works fine, but I need add .watch for automatic this process.

Anyone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
// Require the npm modules we need
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css"),
    terser = require("gulp-terser");

// Looks for a file called styles.css inside the css directory
// Copies and renames the file to styles.min.css
// Minifies the CSS
// Saves the new file inside the css directory
function minifyCSS() {
  return gulp.src("./_statika/css/style.css")
    .pipe(rename("style.min.css"))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"));
}

// Looks for a file called app.js inside the js directory
// Copies and renames the file to app.min.js
// Minifies the JS
// Saves the new file inside the js directory
function minifyJS() {
  return gulp.src("./_statika/js/scripts.js")
    .pipe(rename("scripts.min.js"))
    .pipe(terser())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./js"));
}

// Makes both functions available as a single default task
// The two functions will execute asynchronously (in parallel)
// The task will run when you use the gulp command in the terminal
exports.default = gulp.parallel(minifyCSS, minifyJS);
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
gulp.watch("./_statika/css/style.css", minifyCSS);
gulp.watch("./_statika/js/scripts.js", minifyJS);
```

Comment: You should include how this code is added to the default task.

Comment: DiPierro thanks a lot, can you add full code?